# Laravel Eloquent for listing filters name and link to user

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm filtering schools with filters from url and I need to show to user the links for these filters. Well, actually I need to show to user only the filters which after use them not return empty result. I tried with scope and relationships and I have got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'specialties.school_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `id`, `name` from `specialties` where ((select count(*) from `schools` where `specialties`.`school_id` = `schools`.`id` and `specialties` like %""%) >= 1))
```

In my case I need to filter schools by specialties, districts, municipality, city and etc. Here is my example School model:

```
<?php

class School extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'schools';

    public function scopeWhereSpecialties($query, $specialties)
    {
        if( !is_array($specialties) )
        {
            $specialties = [$specialties];
        }

        return $query->where(function($q) use ($specialties)
        {
            foreach($specialties as $specialty){
                $q->where('specialties', 'like', '%"'.$specialty.'"%');
            }
        });
    }

    // I just delete other scopes to shorten the code

    public function listSchoolsEndUser($filters)
    {
        $schools_data = School::query();

        foreach($filters as $filter => $value)
        {
            call_user_func(array($schools_data, 'where' . studly_case($filter)), $value);
        }

        return $schools_data->paginate(12);
    }

    public function listFilters($filters)
    {
        $specialties_filters = Specialty::select('id', 'name')->whereFilterAvailable($filters)->get()->toArray();

        return $specialties_filters;
    }
}
```

And there is my example Specialty model:

```
<?php

class Specialty extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'specialties';

    public function scopeWhereFilterAvailable($query, $filters)
    {
        $specialty = $this->id;
        return $query->where(function($q) use ($specialty, $filters)
        {
            $q->whereHas('school', function($q) use ($specialty, $filters) {
                $q->where('specialties', 'like', '%"'.$specialty.'"%');
            });
        });
    }

    public function school(){
        return $this->belongsTo('School');
    }
}
```

Table structure of school is similat to:

```
____________________________________
| id | name    | specialties       |
|____|_________|___________________|
| 1  | example | ["1","2","3","4"] |
|____|_________|___________________|
```

And table structure of specialties is similat to:

```
________________
| id | name    |
|____|_________|
| 1  | example |
|____|_________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with `select('id', 'name')` you restrict the query to only those attributes and thus `school_id` is not available. You should include all columns that you (and your relationshipos) need:

```
$specialties_filters = Specialty::select('id', 'name', 'school_id')->whereFilterAvailable($filters)->get()->toArray();
```

Maybe `lists()` is an option here as well. It constructs an array with one attribute as key and the other as value:

```
$specialties_filters = Specialty::whereFilterAvailable($filters)->lists('name', 'id');
```

Comment: but there isn't school_id column in specialties table and when I try your code the error is the same

Comment: Ah, now I looked at your tables a bit closer. Storing the specialties primary keys in an array in the school table is the wrong approach. Add a `school_id` in the specialties table or create a pivot table if it's a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Why is it everyone answers questions for these people with like 5 reputation, but they don't up vote?  It isn't a bad question right?  Up vote that thing!